# How to make is_dir($FoLdEr) case insensitive in php?

Tags: php, case-insensitive

I need `is_dir()` to don't care about if the folder or the argument is upper or lower case, or a mix of upper and lower.

So if the foldername is "My Folder" and I run `is_dir("mY FoLdEr")` the result should be `true`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not up to PHP. That's up to operating system and filesystem that PHP is running on. Windows is case insensitive but every version of Unix/Linux is case sensitive.

Let me put it another way: `is_dir()` is basically a wrapper to a system call or it will use the results of system calls on file info. Those system calls will either return something or not if, by the rules of that operating system and filesystem, a file is found with the matching name. PHP can't change this so no you can't just make `is_dir()` be case insensitive on Linux.

The best you can do is get a list of files in the directory and loop through them to test to see if any match a case insensitive comparison to what you're looking for.

**Note:** you might get multiple hits eg "HOME" and "Home" will both match "home". What would such a function (that you want) do in this case?

Alternatively you can change all your filenames to lowercase and then you can use the lowercase version of your input to find the specified file.

Comment: So there is no way to make `is_dir()` to don't care about this?

Comment: @Johan - there is, but as cletus' note points out, such a function would probably be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions. I am not quite sure on the syntax in php:

```
is_dir("[mM][yY] [fF][oO][lL][dD][eE][rR]")
```

They may be a better `regexp` for it.

Comment: Use of regular expressions is not possible in `is_dir`. However, there is a function `glob` for a similar effect: `glob('{mM}{yY} {fF}{oO}{lL}{dD}{eE}{rR}', GLOB_BRACE)`

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue where I needed to validate a directory path. I didn't want to have a mixture of similarly name directories in different cases. i.e. **my\dir** and **My\Dir**. I tried the grep approach mentioned by [Filip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/449012/filip) `glob('{mM}{yY} {fF}{oO}{lL}{dD}{eE}{rR}', GLOB_BRACE)` but I found that if the directory name was longer than about 8 characters it would grind to a halt. So this is my solution for a case insensitive `is_dir()`;

```
$path  = '/';
$parts = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/My/DirecTorY/pATh');

foreach($parts as $key => $dir) {
    $isUnique = true;

    if (is_dir($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dir)) {
        $path .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dir;
        $isUnique = false;
    } else {
        $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($path);
        $name = strtolower($dir);

        foreach($iterator as $file) {
            $filename = $file->getFilename();
            if($file->isDir() && strtolower($filename) == $name) {
                $path .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
                $isUnique = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if($isUnique) {
        $path .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR 
              . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array_slice($parts, $key));
        break;
    } 
}

var_dump($isUnique, $path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirty way could be getting list of all directories in actual dir and compare theirs strtolower()-ed names with desired name

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

```
function is_dir_ci($path){
    $glob_path='';
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($path); $i++) {
        if(preg_match('/^\p{Latin}+$/',$path[$i])){
            $glob_path.='['.strtolower($path[$i]).strtoupper($path[$i]).']';
        }else 
            $glob_path.=$path[$i];
    }
    return !empty(glob($glob_path,GLOB_BRACE));
}

is_dir_ci('/path/With/Cap-Case or not/');
```

it basicaly does transform the path from

`'/path/With/Cap-Case or not/'`

to

`'/[pP][aA][tT][hH]/[wW][iI][tT][hH]/[cC][aA][pP]-[cC][aA][sS][eE] [oO][rR] [nN][oO][tT]/'`

But as only knowing **there is** dir with some cap-letters changed, I think a better function should be:

```
function get_correct_dir($path){
    $glob_path='';
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($path); $i++) {
        if(preg_match('/^\p{Latin}+$/',$path[$i])){
            $glob_path.='['.strtolower($path[$i]).strtoupper($path[$i]).']';
        }else 
            $glob_path.=$path[$i];
    }
    return glob($glob_path,GLOB_BRACE);
}

var_export( get_correct_dir('/path/With/Cap-Case or not/') )
```